# How to change a criterion to an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the following criterion:
$${2{\pi}f_m} < {\frac{1}{RC}} = 2{\pi}f_c$$

I am given values where: 
$f_m = 1000$ 
$R = 8000$ 
$f_c = 100000$ 
I am required to solve for C using the above criterion.

How can I change the above criterion to an equation, so that I can solve for a particular variable?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: well you have $\frac{1}{RC} = 2\pi f_{c}$, $f_{c} = 100000$, and $R=8000$. So, you can find the value of $C$. Then you should check whether $2\phi f_{m} < \frac{1}{RC}$ is satisfied or not.

I am unsure myself about what you actually want to ask.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra If I am solving for C can I omit ${2{\pi}f_m}$ from the equation? Would the equation look like this $\frac{1}{RC} = 2{\pi}f_c$?

Comment: Yes, you are right and in fact you can do it. The expression $a< b = c$ actually can be written as $a<b$ AND $b=c$. Most people write $a<b=c$ for the sake of brevity.

Comment: @EvanWilliamChandra Thank you